# Accessing meteor collection through template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm trying to access the contents of a meteor collection on a template. The first step is a search that allows the app to display specific items from the Mongo collection named **players**, then when you click on the item it takes you to the **showPerson** page that displays the contents of those items. So far I have been able to get the search to work, but when you click on a item it renders the new page but does not populate data.

I've tried going through answers on here but have been unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Also if you notice in `<template name="search">` I have `__originalId`. I've also tried `_id` and `id` but still no success. Speaking of ID's whats the difference between these?

And my extra packages are

```
easy:search
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
arillo:flow-router-helpers
```

I also still have autopublish and insecure installed so i guess it's not a subscription issue??

Disclaimer--I'm new to meteor and javascript so please feel free to tear this apart and hold my hand :)

My html is

Search options

```
<template name="search">
  {{> EasySearch.Input index=playersIndex}}

  <ul>
    {{#EasySearch.Each index=playersIndex}}
      <li>Name of the player: <a href="{{pathFor 'showPerson'}}/{{__originalId}} ">{{name}}</a> {{name}}  Score of the Player:  ({{score}})</li>
    {{/EasySearch.Each}}
  </ul>

  {{> EasySearch.LoadMore index=playersIndex}}

  {{#EasySearch.IfNoResults index=playersIndex}}
    <div class="no-results">No results found!</div>
  {{/EasySearch.IfNoResults}}
</template>
```

Page that is supposed to display contents

```
<template name="showPerson">
  <h1>Show Person Details: {{name}}</h1>
  <div class="row">
 name: {{name}}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    score: {{score}}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    age: {{age}}
  </div>
</template>
```

My Javascript is

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  let cursor = PlayersIndex.search('Marie'); // search all docs that contain "Marie" in the name or score field

  console.log(cursor.fetch()); // log found documents with default search limit
  console.log(cursor.count()); // log count of all found documents
});


Template.search.helpers({
  playersIndex: () => PlayersIndex // instanceof EasySearch.Index  
  });


Template.update.helpers({
    exampleDoc: function () {
        return Players.findOne();
  }
});



Template.myMenu.helpers({
  items: function(){
    return MyCollection.find();
  }
});


Template.myMenu.events({
  'onChange #mySelect': function(ev){
    ...handle the event.
  }
});
```

And my routes

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {

   action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("home");
   }
});



FlowRouter.route( '/players/:_id', {
  name: "showPerson",
  action: function( params ) {
    console.log( params._id );

    BlazeLayout.render( 'showPerson'); 
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/hello', {
   action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('hello');
   }
});
```

And if it helps here is two screenshots

[Home page with search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRH4e.png)

[showPerson page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdJ4I.png)

Database and schema

```
Players = new Mongo.Collection('players');

 PlayersSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "name": {
    type: String,
    label: "Business Name"
  },
  "address": {
    type: String,
    label: "Address"
  },
  "website": {
    type: String,
    label: "Website",
    optional: true
  },
}
Players.attachSchema( PlayersSchema );



PlayersIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
  collection: Players,
  fields: ['name', 'score'],
  engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB ()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First wrap your `showPerson` template with a `{{#with}}`

```
<template name="showPerson">
{{#with person}}
  <h1>Show Person Details: {{name}}</h1>
  <div class="row">
    name: {{name}}
  </div>
  //etc...
{{/with}}
</template>
```

Then add a helper to provide the data for the `{{#with}}`:

```
Template.showPerson.helpers({
  person() {
    return Players.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer works perfectly. I do have one question though. When i use __originalID i receive the results as such `zc3SpXvua3qCiibCJ` , and get results on the page, but when i use _id i receive nothing and the console prints the id in a weird format `zc3SpXvua3qCiibCJ""{}` why is this. The only reason  I am asking is because all examples I see use _id instead of __originalID

Comment: Can you show some sample data from your collection? `_id` is the default unique identifier automatically created for all collections. `_originalID` has no special meaning in Meteor afaik.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my question

Comment: I figured out the ID issue. It has to do with `meteor easy-search` package. The package adds extra characters to `_id ` this explains why `_originalID ` works.

Answer (score 0):

Your showPerson template does not show any data because you don't give any data to it.
You should fetch the player data from the collection that match the id given in the route /players/:_id

Go read https://guide.meteor.com to get more info.